# Use autolayout to set dynamic UIView to match container view

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, resize

I have a UIView in IB that has another UIView within it, which I am using as a container view.  In code, I create three different views and then animate the appropriate one into the container's view depending on the state of the app.  Only one of the three different views will be valid at any given time.  The problem is, when I run on different iPhone's in the simulator, my new subviews are not scaled to match the container view.  I am using autolayout.  For testing purposes, I've set up my subviews to just be a big button that has all it's edges constrained to the superview.  And the container view also has it's edges constrained to it's superview.  What I want is for the subview to match the container's view. i.e the button stretches the entire size of the container view.  When run on different iPhones the size of the container view and therefore the subview should scale proportionally relative to the different iPhone's screen sizes.

Below is the code I use to init my subview and set up it's constraints relative to the container view.

```
UIView *containerView = self.subView;
UIView *newSubview = [[mySubview alloc] init];
[newSubview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.containerView addSubview:newSubview];

[self.containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[self.containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[self.containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[self.containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

I just can't seem to get this to work.  I'm fairly new to autolayout and am not sure what I am doing wrong and would like to stop banging my head against this wall.  Any help would be terrific.  :)

---

************* ADDITIONAL INFO **************

---

Sorry, I've not stated my problem as clearly as I could have.  So here is some more info with screen shots. First, I'll describe what I've done code-wise.

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m, I create MyViewController like this,

```
self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

In viewDidLoad in MyViewController.m, I create mySubview and add it to my containerView and create constraints for it like this,

```
UIView *containerView = self.containerView;
UIView *mySubview = [[MySubview alloc] init];
[mySubview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[containerView addSubview:mySubview];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(mySubview);
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[mySubview]|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:views]];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[mySubview]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
```

And finally in init in MySubview.h I add the nib as a subview like this,

```
- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MySubview" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:[nibArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

A couple of things to note that may help,

In MyViewController.xib, I have a UIView that I am using as the containerView. It has an IBOutlet to UIView* containerView and is the one referenced above.  The only constraints I have for the containerView in IB are, leading, trailing and bottom space to Superview and top space to Superview = 44.

For MySubview.xib, the height and width are 300, (no constraints are used for height or width).  I feel like these sizes should not matter since mySubview is supposed to get constrained to containerView.

In MySubview.xib I have 3 objects, topButton: height = 29, middleView: height = 242 and bottomButton: height = 29. (see attached image) TopButton has leading, trailing and top to Superview constraints and a bottom to middleView constraint.  MiddleView has leading and trailing to Superview constraints and a top to topButton constraint and a bottom to bottomButton constraints. And finally bottomButton has leading, trailing and bottom to Superview constraints and a top to middleView constraint.

What I want to happen is for mySubview to scale to fit the containerView since constraints have been create and added but instead, mySubview gets very large and clips containerView.

Here are some screen shots:

MyViewController.xib, the blue rectangle below the title is my container view and has the IBOutlet containerView.

[image: http://i33.tinypic.com/14o3lmd.png]

MySubview.xib

[image: http://i37.tinypic.com/344ukk3.png]

And finally, the result, which are incorrect.

[image: http://i34.tinypic.com/nbyqua.png]

Instead I would want this, which I have faked just to get the screen shot.

On iPhone 4,

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/w9fp5e/4]

On iPhone 5,

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2z8nldv/4]

As you can see in the fake screen shots, mySubview scales to fit the containerView, even as containerView scales a bit to adjust for the different phone screen sizes.

Hope I did not go overboard with the info.  Any help would be terrific.  I feel like I am close but must be missing one key step.  Grrrrr.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. This basically looks fine, other than some variable name weirdness: Your local variable, `containerView` is equal to `self.subView`, but all of your other lines refer to a different variable, a class property, `self.containerView`. Did you omit a line where you set that `containerView` class property? But when I fixed that, your code worked fine for me.
2. Make sure you're not trying to look at the `frame` immediately after setting the constraints, as the change will not yet be reflected in the `frame` settings. You can do a `[containerView layoutIfNeeded];` if you want to force it to relayout everything based upon the constraints. Also, if you want to confirm `frame` settings, it's better to defer looking at those values until after `viewDidAppear` (i.e. `viewDidLoad` is too early in the view construction process).
3. A minor tweak on your code (and unrelated to your problem), but when I'm setting the constraints within a container view, I often will set not only `NSLayoutAttributeTop` and `NSLayoutAttributeLeading`, like you did, but also `NSLayoutAttributeBottom` and `NSLayoutAttributeTrailing` (rather than `NSLayoutAttributeWidth` and `NSLayoutAttributeHeight`). It accomplishes the same thing as your code, but when using non-zero values, it is a fraction more intuitive.

   Anyway, I just did the following code, permutation of yours, and it works fine:

   ```
   - (IBAction)didTouchUpInsideAddView:(id)sender
   {
       UIView *containerView = self.containerView;
       UIView *newSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; // initializing with CGRectZero so we can see it change
       newSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       newSubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
       [containerView addSubview:newSubview];

       [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:containerView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];

       [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:containerView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];

       [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:containerView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];

       [containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newSubview
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:containerView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];

       // the frame is still `CGRectZero` at this point

       NSLog(@"newSubview.frame before = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newSubview.frame));

       // if not doing this in `viewDidLoad` (e.g. you're doing this in
       // `viewDidAppear` or later), you can force `layoutIfNeeded` if you want
       // to look at `frame` values. Generally you don't need to do this unless
       // manually inspecting `frame` values or when changing constraints in a
       // `animations` block of `animateWithDuration`.

       [containerView layoutIfNeeded];

       // everything is ok here

       NSLog(@"containerView.bounds after = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(containerView.bounds));
       NSLog(@"newSubview.frame after = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newSubview.frame));
   }
   ```
4. You can simplify that code a little using [visual format language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1), e.g.:

   ```
   NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(newSubview);

   [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[newSubview]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
   [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[newSubview]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
   ```

   I find it easier to get the constraints right using visual format language. A little less error-prone (for me, at least). There are, though, some constraints that cannot be represented in visual format language, in which case I fall back to the syntax you outline.
5. In your revised question, you show us an `init` method for your subview, which does *another* `addSubview`. You have to set constraints there, too. Bottom line, wherever you do `addSubview`, you have to set your constraints, e.g.

   ```
   - (id)init
   {
       if(self = [super init])
       {
           NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MySubview" owner:self options:nil];
           UIView *subview = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
           subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

           [self addSubview:subview];

           NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
           [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views]];
           [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views]];
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ahh, yes you are correct, I did mess up my variable names when writing up the question.  Sorry for the confusion.  The visual format language looks nice.   I guess I am staying away from it until I can get this working, then I will switch over to using it.  Baby steps.  :)  Unfortunately, it's still not working for me.  I'm currently looking at the pinning the width and height suggestion and then modifying the outlet constraint in code.  I'm just not sure what i should be changing the constraint constants values to?

Comment: @Feta Precisely what is going wrong? I ask because when I use your code, it works fine. Make sure you're not trying to examine the `frame` settings immediately after setting constraints, as that won't work unless (a) you do it in `viewDidAppear` or later; and/or (b) you force `layoutIfNeeded`. Bottom line, how have you concluded that the constraints aren't working? See my revised answer for a few other observations.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give a more detailed description of what I am doing.  Previously, I was setting my constraints in viewDidLoad, I just changed it to viewDidAppear and also made a call to layoutIfNeeded but I'm still getting the same incorrect results.  :(

Comment: So I just tried your code and it worked, great! Sort of.  :)  When I change "UIView *newSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];" to "UIView *newSubview = [[MySubview alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];"  It does not work and behaves as i have outlined in my edited question.  MySubview loads a nib, I guess i have to look more into that as it seems it could be causing problems.

Comment: @Feta is the auto layout flag turned on in your NIB?

Comment: Getting closer... Yes, the auto layout flag is turned on in my NIBS.  So I was just looking the log output from your code (that i am using), newSubview's frame is correctly changing after the call to layoutIfNeeded.  And it's the correct value for the different phones, great!  The problem is, newSubview is not resized.

Comment: @Feta Aren't you missing a set of constraints? In your subview's `init`, you're doing _another_ `addSubview`. So just repeat the constraint creation process there, too. See point #5 in my revised answer.

Comment: That was it.  I did not realize I had to set constraints for every subview... but of course you do.  Once you said it, I knew it was the missing link (cue music).  :)  Thank you!  I'm just sorry my rating is too low to up-vote you.

Answer (score 1):

In the problem you state "my new subviews are not scaled to match the container view" - but from the description I think they are - the problem is that your container view has no fixed size.

I think that if you set your container view to have a fixed width and height that should do it, you may also need to call

```
[self.containerView layoutSubviews]
```

to force a resize after updating the constraints.

I'd also suggest you swap to using the text based formatting, you could swap out your lines above for something like "H:|[newSubview]|" and "V:|[newSubview]|"

Comment: I think this may be the right line of thinking. How do I update the constraints so they scale relative to the device's screen size? Do I pin the container view's height and width in IB, then hook them up to constraint outlets and change the constants when I create the subviews?  If so, lets say in IB, my container view's height is 400, and that value is correct for iPhone 5, so I would not want to modify it.  How and where would I change it when the app is running on iPhone 4 to get it to scale down a bit to be proportional to it's smaller screen?

Comment: Well, what is the relationship between the views and the size of the screen?  Yes, the size should be dependent on the screen but the goal is to express that in the constraints instead of with fixed numbers.  If say, the containerView height should be 30% of the superview you can drag the height constraint from IB into your controller and use that to set the scaling on load.   You could also try changing the height from an equality (=) to an inequality (>=)

Comment: I think i am doing that.  The containerView has constraints to the super for it's top and bottom that i set in IB.  You say I should "scale on load"  that makes sense to me as well but where do I get that scale factor.  For example, the iPhone 5's height is 1136 and the iPhone 4's height is 960, so i guess there's somewhere i can get a scale factor or 0.845  (960 / 1136)  I know i could do that in code by dividing the current screen height by the screen height that the view was built for but that does not seem right and seems to be something autolayout should handle.  Am I wrong there?

Comment: As it stands, when I create my subview (which has been built for iPhone 5) and constrain it to the container view in code, it has no effect on the the subview's height and the bottom of the view is clipped when displayed on smaller screens like iPhone 4.

Comment: Scale on load was a poor choice of words, rather it should be infer height based off of existing constraints to superview on load.  A mouthful.  Could you post a screenshot?  Is your subview extending beyond the container view on smaller screens, or is the container view already extending beyond the bottom before you add the subview?  Any errors or messages in the logs when it clips?

Comment: I added some screen shots to my original question, hopefully that helps explain what I am doing and what is going wrong.  I'm not getting any errors or messages in the logs.  Also, when I use "po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]" all constraints are valid.