# NSLayoutConstraint for view on UITableView

Tags: autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` as well as a `UIView` that is above the `UITableView` but aligned to the bottom of the screen. Problem is when the user is on a phone call, the `frame` settings don't work, and the `UIView` is pushed below the screen (so it is slightly covered. I'm trying to just align the `UIView` to the view bottom and simply not getting it to align. I have the constraints defined as below:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.signupView];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.signupView];

NSArray *v = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_signupView(70)]-0-|"
                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                     metrics:nil
                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_signupView)];
NSArray *h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_signupView]|"
                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                     metrics:nil
                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_signupView)];
[self.view addConstraints:h];
[self.view addConstraints:v];
```

The height of `signupView` is 70, and it should just be aligned at the bottom of the screen with the width of the entire screen. The above code is putting the view at the top of the view. Is there something i'm missing here? Why is it not aligning with the bottom as I put above? I tried to read the below on this:

http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/

http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/

[Use autolayout to set dynamic UIView to match container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157665/use-autolayout-to-set-dynamic-uiview-to-match-container-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Here is the below that worked for me:

```
NSArray *v = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_signupView(70)]-0-|"
                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline
                                                     metrics:nil
                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_signupView)];
NSArray *h = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_signupView]|"
                                                     options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                     metrics:nil
                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_signupView)];
[self.view addConstraints:h];
[self.view addConstraints:v];
```