# Adding a container view programmatically without storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uicontainerview

I have this in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
    let childViewControllerForPosts = PostsCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    let cView = childViewControllerForPosts.view
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.addChildViewController(childViewControllerForPosts)
    self.view.addSubview(cView)
    childViewControllerForPosts.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleScroll(_:)), name: "cvScrolled", object: nil)

    cView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(view.frame.size.width).active = true
    cView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(view.frame.size.height).active = true
    cView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerForGreyAndPurple.bottomAnchor).active = true
    cView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
```

However, I get an error saying that this is an illegal constraint because it has no common ancestor :(

Here's the error:

`...because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the constraints incorrectly.

You need to first add constraints with parent view and container view, then you also need to add constraints to your container controller. 
**Finally you should add the didMoveToParent in the end of setting all the constraints.**

The example is as follows, you can do a similar thing in your case.

```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        containerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
    ])


  NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.leadingAnchor),
        controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.trailingAnchor),
        controller.view.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.topAnchor),
        controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(containerView.bottomAnchor)
    ])


controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

[Use autolayout to set dynamic UIView to match container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157665/use-autolayout-to-set-dynamic-uiview-to-match-container-view)

Comment: Oh, I had to add my controller to a UIView? Because I added a UIView on the top half part of my screen, and then I attempted to just add the controller (the container) to the bottom.

Comment: No No.. what i gave you was just an example. You need to configure your container, architecturally similar, but you can have it set to different UIViews.